# Session storage errors out

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to javascript and I am attempting to learn session storage for an application. I have followed guides to a T and I still get the same error, I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Here is a super simple code to try I use in JS:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('output', 'input');
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('output'));
```

But I always get an "unspecified error"

I've looked up many guides and tutorials but I cant figure out what im doing wrong

Comment: Are you by any chance opening your website via file? aka "C:\MyWebsite\index.html" and using IE? If I'm right it's a known issue unfortunately https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8816771/

Comment: What is `sessionStorage`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @omerowitz it is a window global https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: The code above works for me. I have a feeling your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: `unspecified error` is definitely an IE thing.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman isn't `unspecified error` an oxymoron?

Comment: @George No oxy just moron ;p

Comment: the code is good what is your browser ? try this code with firefox or chrome to test where is the problem

Comment: @George Just moron... `;P`